# Why this z-index behaviour?

Tags: html, css, z-index

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/tRr34/4/) :

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="first-internal">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="fixed">&nbsp;</div>

#first
{
    position:relative;
}

#first-internal
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:blue;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

#fixed
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:41;
}
```

Why I can't see `#fixed`? It is after `#first`, so it must have more "z-index point" then `#first`. The content of `#fixed` (also if childrens of `#first` have `z-index:9000`) must be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block with greater z-index should be always on top. If you read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) you can see that putting a z-index will create a new stack context, which mean that it will basically create a layer on top of other layers with a smaller z-index, no matter the order in the HTML or css.

So in your case #fixed has a lower z-index than #first-internal, so #first-internal is on top. That's all ;)

BTW, this stack context is badly implemented in IE and it will act differently.

Comment: "So in your case #fixed has a lower z-index than #first-internal, so #first-internal is on top. That's all ;)" This doesnt make sense at all. Before consider the "childrens", z-index elaborate the parents. So, if a parent is the winner regard another parents, its children will be always visible (also if they have z-index:1 and the others 90000). This is why z-index should works...

Comment: +1 for stacking contexts (which can get very confusing). imo this is a more difficult concept to describe than selector specificity

Comment: @markzzz Please read the specification, what you say is wrong. Children are displayed in the same stack context than its parent unless they specify a z-index which make them completely independent from their parents. So actually if your `z-index` is 100 you will be  **always** on top of en element with a `z-index` of 99, no matter your parents. I think that the behaviour you are describing is the one of IE<8 which is not standard.

Comment: I really always understand that parents means in the order of "how elements are displayed". So, just IE<8 have this behaviour...damn..

Answer (score 1):

It's all about [stacking contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) as linked to in the [css visual formatting model documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index). n the context of `body`:

- `#first` (no z-index) <del>qualifies as a positioned descendant with stack level 0</del> this element *does not* start a new stacking context (see below for details)
- `#fixed` (z-index > 0) has a positive stack level and renders on higher

<del>Because of that, regardless of how high you set z-index of `#first` decsendants, they will still remain in a lower stack relative to `#first`</del>

<del>These behaviors are identical to those of layers 6 & 7 respectively, as described in the linked documentation.</del>

### Update:

I've always found [MDN docos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) easier to understand. Basically `#first` *does not start* a new stacking context (it is relatively positioned, but it has the default `z-index:auto`).

This means that `#first-internal` and `#fixed` render within the same stacking context, and the one with higher z-index is rendered on top! This is layer 6 behavior as described in the original spec linked.

Comment: This is what I thought before opening this topic! But is incorrect! Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/tRr34/11/ : you see the red one! Now, high the descendants of #first, putting z-index to 200 : the red box is vanished : http://jsfiddle.net/tRr34/12/

Answer (score -1):

When you make an element to `position:absolute` it doesn't takes any space in the document. Rather it behaves as if its floating. And its a basic nature of HTML/CSS that `position:absolute` objects have lesser `z-index` than `position:relative`.

This is because `position:relative` objects has its own existance, it doesn't float as the `absolute` elements.

I have posted few links below you can have a short study on these two properties :

- http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm
- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/29/an-indepth-coverage-on-css-layers-z-index-relative-and-absolute-positioning/

Hope this clarifies your query.

Comment: Uhm...I have some dubts about! If I have a position relative as first (without z-index) and a position absolute after (without z-index), the last one will be ALWAYS over the first one. That's because z-index, if not written, get a greater value element after element.

Comment: In fact, following your theory, this doesnt make sense : http://jsfiddle.net/tRr34/10/ : if relative "win" then absolute, the content of the relative must be "over" the absolute. In fact, not...